# Dreamweaver CS5.5 BSOD (Blue Screen of Death) help?

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, flash-cs5, incompatibility, bsod

I just finished downloading and installing the trial version of the Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5 but for some reason, whenever I try to run it, I get a BSOD or Blue Screen of Death. I'm pretty sure I meet and exceed the requirements for Windows as defined [HERE](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/tech-specs.html).

I would so much want to try it to see if it's worth buying but as I said, it keeps giving me the BSOD. Has anyone ever encountered this before? Is there a "fix" to this problem? What should I do?

**Additional Note:**
I'm using Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like it went corrupt on the install.  Try uninstalling the trial and then run the CS Clean tool to get the registry entries and other junk removed too:

http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html

Comment: Will this affect all my other Adobe products installed?

Comment: Yes, it's not a pinpoint tool but more of a flamethrower.  If you have the CS5.5 Suite installed, remove all of it and run the tool, then reinstall.  Alternately, just try uninstall/reinstall of DW making sure you remove any files left behind before reinstall.